# Patch object globally throughout modules for testing

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Consider the code below...

Singleton config class

```
# config.py

class SomeConfigObject:
    thing = True

CONFIG = SomeConfigObject()
```

A module that utilizes the config object

```
# some_module.py
from config import CONFIG

def somefn():
    return CONFIG.thing
```

The main program that uses the module

```
# main_program.py
import some_module

def main():
    return some_module.somefn()
```

A test for the main program

```
# test_main_program.py
from main_program import main

def test_main():
    assert main() == True
```

This is a very simplistic example of a singleton 'config' object. In a more complicated codebase, there are many many many files (often nested) that would have from config import CONFIG  so many modules could use that particular config. So, my question is:

**Is there a simple way to patch an object globally through out a code base?**

I've found that using mock would work:

```
# test main_program
from unittest import mock
from main_program import main

class TestConfig:
    thing=True

@mock.patch('main_program.some_module.CONFIG', new=TestConfig())
def test_main():
    assert main() == True
```

But ultimately, **the above is not scalable and is very painful** if there are tens/hundreds of places it is used.